# C# Return JSON instead of a view (MVC)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to use AJAX to recieve a **JSON array** from the **controller**. In **php** you can just return **string** instead of a **view** so you can do something like that:

```
$array = array(
"Hello" => "hi", 
"Whatsup" => sup
);
return json_encode($array);
```

However, in **C#** you have to return **ActionResult** object. So until now I didn't find a good solution for "printing" the **JSON array** as the result.

Comment: Google **JsonResult** like in http://chsakell.com/2013/06/08/retrieve-json-data-from-mvc-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Use `return Json(array);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return JsonResult instead of ActionResult to return your json:

```
  public JsonResult MyAction()
   {
    //DoSomething
    return Json(value);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JsonResult instead of ActionResult return type for your controller action method. Below mentioned path might help you: 
http://binodmahto.blogspot.in/2013/03/all-about-jsonobject.html

Answer (score 0):

Also is right this code:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(value);
}
```